# Rails, check database if uploading data in CSV already exists

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

I'm new to Rails and I would like to know if I can check if data already exists in my database while uploading new data from CSV. So far I haven't found this on the net.

I use a Postgres database. I don't know if I have to check it in Rails or in Postgres. In my database there are some columns like `id`, `personal_id`, `cost_center`. So I will check if one (or more) of my new data has the same `personal_id` with the the same `cost_center` while uploading.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I've tried the solution of @huan son, it works but not the way I need it. So I tried different things and I think a SQL query is in my case the best choice.

`DELETE FROM bookings WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM bookings GROUP BY personal_id, wbs, date, hours, cost_center)`

`Booking.delete_all.where('id NOT IN (?)', Booking.select('MIN(id)').group(:personal_id, :wbs, :date, :hours, :cost_center).map(&:id))`

My SQL query works like the way I want it but I don't know the right "translation" into rails because with the second code above my whole bookings table gets deleted

**Solution**

The solution for my problem is:

`Booking.delete_all(['id NOT IN (?)', Booking.group(:personal_id, :wbs, :date, :hours, :cost_center).pluck('MIN(id)')])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are unique scopes.

You need to define those first in your database migration so postgres is making sure there is no double-value wie [key, key1, key2...]

`add_index :table, [:personal_id, :cost_center_id], :unique => true`

then you need to go into your rails-model and catch that uniqueness at validations.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :personal_id, :scope => :cost_center_id
```

with that, rails is querying every time before creating a object, the database and check if something with the unique-pair-values already exists. if so, its adding it to the @errors of the model, so the model can't be saved

Comment: Wow thank you for your fast answer, I'm gonna try it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use uniqueness validation, but in my experience when importing data from CSV, the problem is that if the item already exists, all the validation does is stop the record being saved. In most examples, you usually want to do something with the matched record. Therefore, I'd suggest you also look at [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by). This allows you to also update existing records from imported data.

So if you have Thing model with a name and cost for example, you may want to identify existing things by name, and update their costs. And create new things where no matching name exists. The following code would do that:

```
name, price = some_method_that_gets_name_and_price_from_csv

thing = Thing.find_or_initialize_by name: name
thing.price = price
thing.save
```

Also have a look at [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) which can be more suitable in some situations. I'd also still keep the validation of uniqueness in the model. I just wouldn't use validation to handle how the data was imported.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution too